# Implementing Call Diversion Feature with Laravel, Twilio PHP SDK, and Twilio JS Client

Tags: laravel, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php

I have successfully implemented a browser call feature using Laravel, the Twilio PHP SDK, and the Twilio JS Client. My setup involves three endpoints:

One endpoint works in conjunction with the Twilio JS client to make browser-based calls.
Another endpoint handles incoming calls to the designated Twilio number.
The final endpoint, callStatus, monitors the status of the calls.
Now, I am trying to add a call diversion feature and would appreciate some guidance. Here's how I envision it working:

A call is initiated from Number A to Number B. If Number B does not answer within a specified timeout period, thus resulting in a 'no-answer' status, the system should then fetch the list of diversion numbers associated with Number B from a MySQL database (managed with Laravel). This list would be an array, where each element is a record containing the diversion number and a corresponding timeout parameter.

Following this, the system should sequentially dial each diversion number. This process continues until one of the diversion numbers picks up, or until all the diversion numbers have been called without any answer. If none of the diversion numbers answer, the call should be terminated. However, if one of the diversion numbers answers, any remaining numbers in the list should not be called.

Could anyone provide some guidance or code samples on how to implement this call diversion feature?